# CMFormatDescriptionRef and CMVideoFormatDescriptionGetDimensions

Tags: ios, ios8, avfoundation

After updating to ios 8, I cant seem to get CMFormatDescriptionRefs Dimensions
it always return 0,0 dimension. already looked at apples Documents but I really cant understand how to apply it.

Here's my existing codes which is working with ios 7 (already tested it with my device with ios 7)

```
   NSArray *ports = [input ports];
AVCaptureInputPort *usePort = nil;
for ( AVCaptureInputPort *port in ports )
{
    if ( usePort == nil || [port.mediaType isEqualToString:AVMediaTypeVideo] )
    {

        usePort = port;
        break;
    }
}

CMVideoFormatDescriptionRef format = [usePort formatDescription];
CMVideoDimensions dim = CMVideoFormatDescriptionGetDimensions(format);
cameraSize = CGSizeMake(dim.width, dim.height);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved my problem by adding an observer for the AVcapture port formatDescription
since in the ios 8 version gives you a "0" value with the old way of getting the ports format description.

the first line adds an observer for AVCapture

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                 selector:@selector(avCaptureInputPortFormatDescriptionDidChangeNotification:)
                                                     name:AVCaptureInputPortFormatDescriptionDidChangeNotification object:nil];`
```

the next line will give you the ports description if the AVCapture changes

```
- (void)avCaptureInputPortFormatDescriptionDidChangeNotification:(NSNotification *)notification {
[self initializeAPI];
NSArray *ports = [deviceInput ports];
AVCaptureInputPort *usePort = nil;
for ( AVCaptureInputPort *port in ports )
{
    if ( usePort == nil || [port.mediaType isEqualToString:AVMediaTypeVideo] )
    {

        usePort = port;
        break;
    }
}

CMFormatDescriptionRef formatDescription = usePort.formatDescription;
if (formatDescription) {
    CMVideoDimensions dimensions = CMVideoFormatDescriptionGetDimensions(formatDescription);
    if ((dimensions.width == 0) || (dimensions.height == 0)) {


        return;
    }
    CGFloat aspect = (CGFloat)dimensions.width / (CGFloat)dimensions.height;
    BOOL is7x = floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) <= NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_7_1;
    if (is7x) {
    }else{
        aspect = 1.f / aspect;

        dimensionForIOS8Above = CGSizeMake(dimensions.width, dimensions.height);
        //NSLog(@"8DIMENSION %f",dimensionForIOS8Above.width);



    }



}
```

}